# PHP Fatal Error: require_once(Mail.php): Failed opening required 'Mail.php'

Tags: php, email, pear

I am encountering a fatal error in my PHP script and would appreciate some assistance in resolving it. It is a Cron job that generates a report every Monday and mails it. It was working fine about a month ago but now I am getting this warning & error in emails. The error message is as follows:

> Warning: require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/healthSolutions/migrations/hs_report.php on line 2
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7/lib/php') in /home/www/healthSolutions/migrations/hs_report.php on line 2

Code snippet:

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //php inif file (error temporary shows)
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The PHP version I am using is PHP 7.

Comment: Well the error message states that the file you want to include cannot be found. Have you checked whether the file really exists in one of the include paths? If it has been working a month ago and now stopped working, something has to have changed - is it possible your project was migrated by a sysadmin, an update was installed or someone just removed the pear package?

Comment: How can I check the file path using the file manager in the control panel? Additionally, since acquiring this project, I have verified that no files have been modified recently, not even in 2023.

Comment: "*How can I check the file path*" - Well the code is looking for the file `Mail.php` inside the folder `/home/www/healthSolutions/migrations`

Answer (score 0):

If you require or include a file in php, it will look at several places to find your file.

It is a combination of your `include_path` + required file name. In your case, it will look at:

- /home/www/healthSolutions/migrations/Mail.php
- /usr/local/php7/lib/php/Mail.php

It will also look at the current working directory + required file name. In case of a cronjob, it will be the home directory of the user. So if you execute it as root, php will look also at:

- /root/Mail.php

If the Mail.php is not found at any of that places, you will get the error you show us.

Because we don't know where is Mail.php in your System, I can't provide any examples, but to solve this you have two good options.

We just assume the file is located at:  `/home/www/healthSolutions/Mail.php`

In your CronJob, just cd first to the path where the Mail.php is:

```
* * * * * cd /home/www/healthSolutions && php migrations/hs_report.php
```

Or you change the path on your `hs_report.php` with `__DIR__` + relative path (Most Recommended)

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . "/../Mail.php";
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //php inif file (error temporary shows)
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Why it has changed?**

I don't know, but it don't need to be a code change. Your CronJob, Home Directory or PHP Setting (inlude_path) may have changed.

Comment: "*It will also look at the current working directory*" - This depends how the CRON is set-up. Nowadays you can set the CRON job to just fetch a webpage and not run the PHP command, but OP didn't specify how the CRON is actually configured.

Comment: I have checked all the files and didnt find Mail.php anywhere so now it is possible that it is the reason for the error. But what i do not know is what Mail.php looks like: its a package of PEAR or custom file?

Comment: That's something we don't/can't know. Does your hosting offer backups? Open a ticket and ask them to restore the file